# Avoiding copy constructor during populating member vector

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics

I have an class `A`:

```
class A {
  int value1;
  int value2;
  std::string text;

public:
  A(int value1, int value2, std::string text) 
   : value1(value1), value2(value2), text(text) { }
};
```

And some "container" class `B`:

```
class B {
  std::vector<A> objects;
  ...

public:
  ...
  void addObject(A a) {
    objects.push_back(a);
  }
};
```

And code:

```
B b;
A a(2, 5, "test");
b.addObject(a);
//I no longer need a from now on
```

My problem is, how to optimize `B::addObject(A a)` to avoid any copying. What I want to achive is to add new object of type `A` to `B.objects` via `B`'s method.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many answers to this question. You could just change your `B` function to `move()`, and `move()` into that function:

```
void addObject(A a) { objects.push_back(std::move(a)); }

b.addObject(std::move(a)); // two moves
```

You could add overloads of `addObject` that take by const lvalue reference and by rvalue reference

```
void addObject(A const& a) { objects.push_back(a); }
void addObject(A&& a) { objects.push_back(std::move(a)); }

b.addObject(std::move(a)); // one move
```

You could add a function template for `addObject` that emplaces:

```
template <class... Args>
void addObject(Args&&... args) { objects.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

b.addObject(2, 5, "test"); // zero moves
```

---

Either way, there's a completely unnecessary copy here:

```
A(int value1, int value2, std::string text) 
: value1(value1), value2(value2), text(text) { }
```

you want:

```
A(int value1, int value2, std::string text) 
: value1(value1), value2(value2), text(std::move(text)) { }
```

Comment: Thank you :) One question: is the `text(std::move(text))` from your side note completely safe in all cases? Also, isn't it something that the compiler would do automatically either way (move instead of copy there because of optimization)?

Comment: @PolGraphic Yes - the constructor owns `text` so it's safe to move from. And no, it won't.

Comment: thanks for the further explanation. It's a bit around the topic but does `A a(2,5,"test"); b.addObject(std::move(a));` in second solution is any different from`b.addObject(A{2,5,"test"});` in case of performance (the second one creates `A` and than moves it or not really)?

Comment: @PolGraphic The moved-from `A` will destroyed within `addObject()` in the second case, but at the end of the scope of `a` in the first case. But, basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

You might change the parameter type of `addObject` and use `emplace_back`, to avoid constructing an object of `A` which won't be used later and copying it into the `vector`. e.g.

```
void addObject(int value1, int value2, std::string text) {
  objects.emplace_back(value1, value2, text);
}
```

and

```
B b;
b.addObject(2, 5, "test"); // construct the element directly into the vector without constructing A
```

Comment: That's an good one, but there is one small problem for me with it. For now I don't relate on `A` constructor parameters anywhere in `B` header file. And with your solution it would require to give more information (that I think is more related to `A` than `B`) in `B` header file. It's more the matter of the appearance tho.

Comment: @PolGraphic I didn't get what you mean, you meant adding `#include "A.h"` in `B.h`? No, it should be same with the one using `push_back`, if the member fucntion is defined in `B.cpp`, it's not needed.

Comment: No, I mean that inside of `B.h` I will have to know & remember about `A` constructor parameters order. And in case of changes with it, I will also have to modify `B.h`.